# PayPal Sandbox account new design, can't login

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Since PayPal changed their website for developers I can't use it anymore. Before I had some test accounts setup and I was able to go in, create buttons and so-on. Now I have imported my previous accounts but I can't log into them, just getting The requested resource () is not available. 404. If I clear browser cache and cookies, it just tells me to login (using my developer-login details, not the test details) and I can't come in. Their support says clear cache and it works... Stupid PayPal.

Anyone knows what to do?

I tried to update Chrome and Firefox to latest versions and then cleared all cookies/cache then logged into developer account and then tried to login to test accounts.

I always get this 404 message: http://snag.gy/rL5t2.jpg

> HTTP Status 404
>   **type** Status report
>   **message**
>   **description** The requested resource () is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/5.5.15-150

Comment: Me too :( Does this problem apply to non-US users only (since the new REST API is for the US only)?

Comment: U might have a point as im located in Sweden. PayPal are saying that they are working on a fix, so I guess it will be fixed in a couple of days anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're aware of this issue and are working on getting it resolved as soon as possible. In the interim, you can manually remove the '/se/' from the URL included in the screenshot, which will bring you to the correct page (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/home).
Sorry for the inconvenience. We'll get this fixed soon!

Comment: When I got back sandbox login ? I can't test paypal now.